Playbook using equals (=) instead of traditional flow collection syntax
I found a playbook that uses the following syntax:
- name: install apache2
  apt: name=apache2 update_cache=yes state=latest

- name: enabled mod_rewrite
  apache2_module: name=rewrite state=present
  notify:
    - restart apache2

This syntax uses equals (=):
apt: name=apache2 update_cache=yes state=latest

whereas I normally see something like the following when flow collection syntax is used:
apt: { name: apache2, update_cache: yes, state: latest }

Is the syntax that uses = documented somewhere?

It is commonly called k=v syntax (short of for key=value) and still holds the purpose to allow you to run task(s) in ad-hoc commands. But the general consensus is to try to avoid it in YAML playbooks.

And since this article you are referring to is 9 years old, well you will indeed find not-so-recommended-anymore syntax there.

Jeff Geerling does have an article about it, the article stems from a discussion with Michael DeHaan, creator of Ansible. This article can be found here : https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/yaml-best-practices-ansible-playbooks-tasks
